# Windows 7 Freezes at Login Screen?

Tags: windows-7, freeze

When it powers on, it comes to the login page and freezes. The mouse won’t move and I can’t type in anything into the password field. The disk access looks busy, which I know is typical when a PC starts, but even after it eventually slows down, neither the mouse nor keys will work. I tried firing it up in the various Safe Modes but the results are the same.

I cannot afford to loose the data on this computer so reinstalling Windows is not an option.

Comment: Have you tried a start-up repair CD? Also consider using a Linux live-cd to boot from cdrom and copy important data that way.

Comment: As i said it neither the keyboard nor the mouse work.

Comment: Did you try an external mouse and keyboard?

Comment: Also, can you remove the hard drive and stick it into another pc?

Comment: The mouse and the keyboard works if i use a live cd system.

Comment: Im using a laptop and havent enough skills to open it.

Comment: @anonyme It looks like you have used two different accounts. If you want to have them merged into one, you can register them and use the "contact" link at the bottom of the page to request a merge.

Comment: I'd add that this should let you post comments, rather than posting comments as answers

Comment: How many hours have you let it set at the login screen, it might be trying to repair something, if left alone for a while it may succeed.

Comment: If the disk access light is constantly on then it may be a hard disk problem and it may be worth looking at copying your files off using your LiveCD and a USB hard disk. Once you've got a backup that you're happy with I would recommend doing a factory restore so that Windows is clean. if you still experience the same problem then I would begin to think about replacing the hard disk.

Comment: I just wait the disk access light off to shut down the computer by the button.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me on an older laptop after I tried upgrading the device drivers for the graphics card. It looked like everything was ok, but after the animated boot logo nothing appeared (still heard the startup sound, when I typed my password it logged in, but the screen was frozen).

If you can still access the keyboard (i. E.  Pressing caps lock lights up the indicator on the keyboard), this is likely the issue.

Start windows in VGA mode (use some Google-fu), and see if that won't help so you can remote the graphics driver and install it again. You should be good to go if that's all it is